# Can't assign value with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I need to assign a value to a `var` depending on the value obtained from another `var`, but it gives me undefined.

I need to give discount depending on the days in advance that you made a reservation
e.g.

```
<input type="date" id="arriveDate">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

The case is that i need to calculate the days between today and `arriveDate`. There's no problem with that (but any comment will be welcomed)

in js i do it this way

```
var today = Date.now();
var arriveDateInserted = new Date(document.getElementById("arriveDate").value);

var diffDays = Math.round(((arriveDateInserted - today)/86400000)+1);
```

Now, i need to give some discount depending on how many days in advance is the reservation made.
I tried with ternary operator, like this.

```
var discount = diffDays < 61 ? 0:
    diffDays > 60 && diffDays < 91 ? 0.10:
    diffDays > 90 && diffDays < 121 ? 0.15;
```

But i don't even have an `alert(discount)`

Any help will be VERY appreciated :)

Comment: Your final ternary does not have a `: <else>` to go with it.  Also keep in mind that many people, including myself, are going to suggest you not chain ternaries like this, as it decreases readability.  EDIT: And given that you are having an issue with getting it to work, you as well appear to be having an issue reading it.  And **you are the one programming it**.

Comment: If you are bent on using ternary, as an opinion at-least wrap the conditionals in parenthesis for more readability.

Comment: i wasn't aware of the `<else>` in the ternary.
Thanks for the comments, il keep them in mind

Comment: That's a very confusing statement, given that you are working with ternaries.

Comment: i'm not "working" exactly, i'm exploring. I'm very noob in coding, especially in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console, you're probably getting a syntax error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

You're missing the `else` in the later condition:

```
diffDays > 90 && diffDays < 121 ? 0.15 /* Here should be a : and an else condition
```

Example:

```
var discount = diffDays < 61 ? 0 :
    diffDays > 60 && diffDays < 91 ? 0.10 :
    diffDays > 90 && diffDays < 121 ? 0.15 : 0.20;
```

I would advise to avoid using nested ternary conditions for better reading:

```
let discount = 0;
if (diffDays > 60 && diffDays < 91) {
    discount = 0.10;
} else if (diffDays > 90) {
    discount = 0.15;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind the logic could be simplified.  If it fails the first if, it has to be > 60.  Same with the last conditional for > 90

Comment: @Taplar agreed.